# react server side and client side routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router, server-side-rendering

Im new to react
The project I'm on working is divided into multiple applications like core, common, template etc.

- core - core functionalities like store, code split, etc
- common - common code like controls
- template - the project team to build own business application

Currently each page is rendered as server side rendering need to implement client side routing after the initial service side routing.

Any advise how this can be achieved?

Comment: You can look into next.js. It is react based with SSR first.

Comment: for now I cant use nextjs, need to use react